# Spark error with spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

i'm trying to work with cassandra-mesos-spark and i would like to ask if someone can help me with this error, i used spark 2.2 try connector 1.6.11 and others but i cannot find out why i'm getting this

Environment:

- spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
- datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.7-s_2.11
- scala 11
- Mesos cluster
- Python application with pyspark

Code:

```
import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sp_conf = SparkConf()
sp_conf.setAppName("spark_test")
sp_conf.setMaster("mesos://192.168.1.10:5050")
sp_conf.set("spark.local.dir", "/home/user/spark-temp")
sp_conf.set("spark.mesos.executor.home", "/home/user/spark")
sp_conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.1.51")
sp_conf.set("spark.jars.packages", "datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.7-s_2.11")
sp_conf.set("spark.mesos.coarse", "True")
sp_conf.set("spark.network.timeout","800")

sc = SparkContext(conf=sp_conf)

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sys.stdout.write("\rGetting rows...")
sys.stdout.flush()

sqlContext.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="opt_instruments", keyspace="fxinstrumentsdb")\
    .load().show()
```

ERROR:

```
datastax#spark-cassandra-connector added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;2.0.7-s_2.11 in spark-packages
    found com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 in spark-list
    found org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 in spark-list
    found commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.9.3 in central
    found commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.2 in spark-list
    found joda-time#joda-time;2.3 in spark-list
    found io.netty#netty-all;4.0.33.Final in central
    found org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8 in spark-list
:: resolution report :: resolve 1338ms :: artifacts dl 22ms
    :: modules in use:
    com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 from spark-list in [default]
    commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.9.3 from central in [default]
    commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.2 from spark-list in [default]
    datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;2.0.7-s_2.11 from spark-packages in [default]
    io.netty#netty-all;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
    joda-time#joda-time;2.3 from spark-list in [default]
    org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 from spark-list in [default]
    org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8 from spark-list in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   8   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   8   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 8 already retrieved (0kB/31ms)
2018-04-07 19:28:45 WARN  Utils:66 - Your hostname, themachine resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.10 instead (on interface enp1s0)
2018-04-07 19:28:45 WARN  Utils:66 - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
2018-04-07 19:28:46 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2018-04-07 19:28:47 WARN  SparkConf:66 - In Spark 1.0 and later spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
Warning: MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY is deprecated, use MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY instead. Future releases will not support JNI bindings via MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY.
I0407 19:28:51.387593  5128 sched.cpp:232] Version: 1.5.0
I0407 19:28:51.436372  5120 sched.cpp:336] New master detected at master@192.168.1.10:5050
I0407 19:28:51.447155  5120 sched.cpp:351] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
I0407 19:28:51.464504  5119 sched.cpp:751] Framework registered with 3c2a29b3-d69f-4982-802e-88342d5c42fd-0038
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]2018-04-07 19:30:56 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.8.0.6, executor 1): java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "tradeunitsprecision", "minimumtrailingstopdistance", "displayprecision", "maximumtrailingstopdistance", "marginrate", "piplocation", "name", "type", "minimumtradesize", "displayname", "maximumpositionsize", "maximumorderunits" FROM "fxinstrumentsdb"."opt_instruments" WHERE token("name") > ? AND token("name") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/package$ScalaReflectionLock$
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:323)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.com$datastax$spark$connector$rdd$CassandraTableScanRDD$$fetchTokenRange(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:339)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$17.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:367)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.hasNext(CountingIterator.scala:12)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/package$ScalaReflectionLock$
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ReflectionLock$.<init>(ReflectionLock.scala:5)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ReflectionLock$.<clinit>(ReflectionLock.scala)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.<init>(TypeConverter.scala:75)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$.<clinit>(TypeConverter.scala)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:50)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.BigIntType$.converterToCassandra(PrimitiveColumnType.scala:46)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.ColumnType$.converterToCassandra(ColumnType.scala:231)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$11.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:312)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$$anonfun$11.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:312)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.createStatement(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:312)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.package$ScalaReflectionLock$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 44 more
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you did not package in the [spark sql dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11/2.2.0)

Comment: I tried to recompile, create new pip package and install again but the same. Can you share more details about packaging

Answer (score 0):

Hi @panosd seems the connector doesnt work with 2.3.0 yet, there is an open pr [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/pull/1171). +1 as well so that it can be brought to attention and merged asap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using HDFS and everything is better and faster, after that I can save the whole calculations to cassandra db for another part.